# C Arrays and code in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, struct

Can someone please share an example of C/Objective-C code where we:

- declare a c structure with some int properties (a, b, c)
- create (in objective-c) a C array that contains items from the previously mentioned structure
- call (in objective-c) a c method that takes the created array as an argument

(Optionally)

- call (in objective-c) an objective-c method that takes the created array as an argument
- call (in c) an objective-c method that takes the created array as an argument

Comment: you want an example for each of the five items?

Comment: This seems like homework, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Objective C is a pure superset of ANSI C. So the variable types and struct declarations would be identical with those in C, as you can find in any book on C.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to C and Objective-C and an actual code example will make things clearer for me. I am already learning C and objective-C but I need an answer to the question ASAP.

Comment: the same as c.


whatever you're doing for c is valid objective-c code.